# Not able to save the values to localMongoDB after certain records using React Native

Tags: json, mongodb, react-native

I'm developing an Android Application in React Native in which I'm saving JSON data to local Mongo DB. The Data is getting saved in Local Mongo DB but after a certain amount of data it is giving me an error like this `Error: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.` and my saved data get erased. Also when I checked the DB size from Android Studio (data -> data -> com.packagename -> database) I found that if DB size gets beyond 2MB it is giving me this error. Any Idea How should I overcome this problem?

I have used Emulator as well as Physical Device, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: It's seems like the problem is the structure of your DB. Check what could happen with CursorWindow

Comment: Yes, I read the Issues section of react-native-local-mongodb in which Author has mentioned that he is using Asyncstorage is an option to store the data which limit is 2 MB. Thats why it is giving such Error. So What is the best option in react native to store the huge data.

Comment: I found this[https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native] Apache based db as a good solution, I wanted to save a big json an retrieve it. It worked very good and simple. Also here you will find full api list: https://pouchdb.com/api.html

Comment: Do you have any working example of that?